# MySql/Php - How to retrieve/check a message is new to a user

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a forum where people can create question and wait for answers. I need a way to check if a message is new to user or the message if already seen. If the message is new i need to provide an alert when the user logs in.

What is the best way/architecture to accomplish this?

Comment: put an ajax call when the user logs in and check in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a table `views` like that

```
- questionID
- userID
- lastMessageRead
```

You keep in `lastMessageRead`, ID of last message saw by user which ask the question.
With that, you can check if `lastMessageRead` is ID of last answer, query number of new messages for this question etc...

---

Here is an example of how to get questions with new messages and number of new messages in each with example tables.

```
Table: answers
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|   answerID   |    questionID    |    userID    |    date    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+

Table: questions
+--------------------------------------------+
|   questionID   |    userID    |    date    |
+--------------------------------------------+

Table: views
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|   questionID   |    userID    |    lastMessageRead    |
+-------------------------------------------------------+

SELECT q.*, COUNT(*) AS nbMessages
FROM answers a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN questions q
        ON a.questionID = q.questionID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN views v
        ON v.questionID = q.questionID
WHERE q.userID = 10 # ID of current user
AND ( a.answerID > v.lastMessageRead OR v.lastMessageRead IS NULL )
GROUP BY q.questionID
HAVING nbMessages > 0
```

Comment: Here , one problem i can foresee is that,We need go the 'views' table and update the lastmessageRead value evertytime the logged in user creates/deletes new messages.

Comment: There is no need to update lastMessageRead at each message creation/deletion of messages. This field as to be updated only when user read a question to insert id of last answer read (and if he hasn't read it before).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table in your database called `messages`, you could add an additional field to store its "read" status. You could call it `is_new` and its datatype would be `tinyint`.

```
Table: messages
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|   id   |    from    |    to    |    content    |  is_new    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When a message is created, the `is_new` field should default to `1` (true). When a user logs in, retrieve user's messages from the DB and those with `is_new == 1`, display as a new message or set up the appropriate alert. After the user reads or views the message, update `is_new` to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

A basic way to achieve this is to introduce a new column to your 'answers' table; a column that would indicate whether the question-creator had seen the answer.

Let's call this column `seen`. It defaults to '0', and should be an integer with a length of one character.

The idea is to `UPDATE` this to '1' when the user visits the answer's page (if that's how your system works).

Next, it is simply a matter of `SELECT`ing the `COUNT` of the records that have a `seen` value of '0'.

Then use an `if` statement to check whether the count exceeds zero in value, and configure your alert accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For the message keep some flag field like is_new in the database to check if the message is new or not.

```
if(is_new == 0){
    //show alert or message to the user
    //set is_new = 1 in the database
}else{
    // Message is already read.
}
```

keeping the field Boolean should do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can log the creation date/time of the message and the last login date/time of the user. If the message was created after the last login it is new.

Answer (score 0):

you need a table for user_messages to keep user id and message and put a message flag field for detect (unread / read or deleted...) on this table.

after you call user login immediately make a query on user_messages table with user id and message flag to detect unread mesages.

then you can make alert to user any notification as you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution. 
**STEP-1:** In the message table make a new column. The type will be string. If any user see the message, it will add #USER_ID#, to that table column. 
**STEP-2:** When ever a new user come to see the message,  check it with the existing column. If not available, message not seen and you can update the column.

Example: user id 1,2,3 have already seen the message. so the column will be #1##2##3# . 
if user 2 come to see the message, check #2# exist in the column or not.

```
if (strpos('#1##2##3#', '#2#') !== false) {
    echo 'seen';
}else{
    echo 'not seen';
}
```

if user 7 come to see the message, check #7# exist in the column or not.

```
if (strpos('#1##2##3#', '#7#') !== false) {
    echo 'seen';
}else{
    $new_string_for_table = '#1##2##3#'.'#7#';
    // update the column of the table
    // make the alert
 }
```